how can I dynamically import PNG files based on their filenames?
I'm new in RN and try to build react native using expo app, and it need to render logo based on user currency, so first i have build this component to dynamicall import png files based on their name,
// the filesnames are match with the user currency
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

interface CurrencyType {
  currency: string;
}

const CurrencyLogo: React.FC<{ currency: CurrencyType }> = ({ currency }) => {
  const logoFileName = `${currency}.png`;

  let imageSource = require(`../../assets/currency-icon/${logoFileName}`);

  return <Image source={imageSource} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />;
};

export default CurrencyLogo;

and import it in my main screen but it got error like
Error: TransformError app/helpers/CurrencyLogo.tsx: app/helpers/CurrencyLogo.tsx:Invalid call at line 35: require(`../../assets/currency-icon/${logoFileName}`)]

Kinda stuck in this problem now,
I have tried to use Import as typescript suggested but i got another complicated error,
And another one solution in mind is creating index to export all the png, but got tackle by ts cause it was not a module, obviously it is png
is there something wrong with my component ?
Please help
Thank you in advance
ps. just in case i attach my package.json here text
